# ChangeNotifier on non-widget classes

Tags: flutter

We've just started developing our first Flutter app and we are running into a small problem with ChangeNotifier applied to a non-widget class and the disposal of objects of this class. We get exceptions when a future returns after the class has been disposed, we call notifyListeners after the future returns.

I've seen questions suggesting to use the mounted property to check if the object is disposed, but this is only available in widgets. The ChangeNotifier class uses it's own check to see if it's been disposed, but we can't call those methods (and neither should we, I think)

My current idea is that we should use a widget class, and not apply ChangeNotifier on any non-widget class. But I can't find any similar problems, or some documentation telling me best practices/guidelines.

```
class ExampleClass extends ChangeNotifier {
  ExampleClass() {
  }

  final ExampleService _service = ExampleService();

  List<Stuff> stuff;

  Future<void> DoStuff() async {    
    stuff = await _service.getStuff();    
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

We're looking for a way to properly handle the callbacks/returning futures and only call notifyListeners if the object has not been disposed.

Comment: please expand your code with the part where you call `addListener` on an instance of the `ExampleClass`, and the listeners themselves.

Comment: We dont explicitly call addListeners, we use the class as: ChangeNotifierProvider< ExampleClass > in the builder method of a different widget. The Exampleclass is then used as a viewModel in a widget tree.